# What does source follower mode mean?

Tags: transistors, circuit-design, cmos, source-follower, common-drain

I've been trying to build a CMOS-level XOR gate. I've been told my implementation won't work because some of the transistors are in "source follower mode".

I've tried looking this up, but I can't find a simple description of the term.

In simple terms, what does source follower mode mean?

(Here's the XOR circuit for reference)

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f61ZEZ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a source follower.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fRroad.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The output will be equal to the input minus the MOSFET's threshold voltage; the source 'follows' the gate. It's a configuration with no voltage gain (i.e. gain ≈ 1), but high current gain. The lack of voltage gain means it's to be avoided in logic circuitry; you want outputs that snap high or low quickly, even if the input goes a bit slowly.

In your schematic, transistors M8, M7, M3, and M4 are source followers.

Answer (score 1):

A source follower configuration is a MOSFET configuration in which the output is taken from the source side of the MOSFET. When operated as a linear amplifier, the output potential on the source of the MOSFET is approximately \$V_{th}\$ less than the potential at the gate. So, the output/source signal "follows" (at a lower level) the input/gate voltage.

There are indeed MOSFETs in your schematic configured as source followers.

Comment: So it's considered a "source follower" because the: "Source Voltage -> Follows -> the Voltage of the Gate"?

Comment: Yes, as long as the MOSFET is conducting.

Comment: What causes this to happen?

Comment: If the gate-to-source voltage is high enough, the MOSFET will conduct and "pull-up" the source.